# My font face isn't working on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, font-face

For some reason, my font face is not showing up in google chrome. It works with other browsers, even on android mobile web browsers.  I read many post on why it could be (google chrome update, etc) but I'm not sure what is the issue or how to fix it.  I am hoping some one could look at my code and see if their is anything wrong.

My Font face CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
src: url('sourcesanspro-regular.eot');
src: url('sourcesanspro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('sourcesanspro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('sourcesanspro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('sourcesanspro-regular.svg#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

 }




@font-face {
font-family: 'source_sans_problack';
src: url('sourcesanspro-black.eot');
src: url('sourcesanspro-black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('sourcesanspro-black.woff') format('woff'),
     url('sourcesanspro-black.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('sourcesanspro-black.svg#source_sans_problack') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
font-family: 'source_sans_probold';
src: url('sourcesanspro-bold.eot');
src: url('sourcesanspro-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('sourcesanspro-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('sourcesanspro-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('sourcesanspro-bold.svg#source_sans_probold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

My CSS where it is implemented:

```
.headerBarText      {font-family:'source_sans_proregular';
                     font-size:37pt;
                     color:#FFF;
                     font-weight:bold;
                     padding-bottom:0px;
                     padding-top:7px;
                     padding-left:15px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. The link to the CSS file needed a capitol letter and another issue that i figured out was that the font that I was calling in my "font-family" request was incorrectly spelled.